# XeLaTeX Polyglossia does not load language

Tags: xetex, miktex, polyglossia

I try to use XeLaTex with localisation to another language, in my case German.
But when I compile the following minimal code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{de}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    Test Test Test Test \TeX \XeTeX
    \caption{Eine Abbildung}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get this error message:

```
Package polyglossia Warning: File gloss-de.ldf does not exist!
(polyglossia)                I will nevertheless try to use hyphenation pattern
s for de. on input line 4.

Package polyglossia Warning: \setlocalhyphenmin useless for unknown language de
on input line 4.

Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `De'
(polyglossia)              
I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on input line 4.
```

Nevertheless a pdf is produced though it has the wrong localisation.
The used command is `xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode polyglossia_problem.tex`.

I use the MiKTeX distribution under Windows 7 64-bit.

What can I do to load the missing files? The `latex` pendant with babel works on my machine.

Comment: The correct command is `german`, not `de`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`polyglossia` is complaining because `de` is not the correct command, you need to issue `german` instead. In this case, the code will compile with 0 errors.

[image]

Some notes:

1. the `\` after `\TeX` is there to preserve the space that comes afterwards.
2. the `german` language has some options for the `polyglossia` package. For example, `spelling` can be

> *"new (= 1996) or old (= 1901): indicates whether hyphenation patterns for traditional (1901) or reformed (1996) orthography should be used."*

You can check the [Section 6.8 of the Manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf) for more options.

And here's the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    Test Test Test Test \TeX\ \XeTeX
    \caption{Eine Abbildung}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could mention `spelling=new`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Never used it before. Is that about hyphenation with modern spelling?

Comment: @Johannes_B I'll add that.

Comment: Sí, new spelling and hyphenation.

Comment: @chr Don't worry! Everything seems obvious after you understand it. Besides, it happens to everyone.